# Is he arrived yet? Has he arrived yet?

Tags: grammar

My Japanese friend asked me why we can say "Is he gone?" but we can't say "Is he arrived yet?". I corrected it to "Has he arrived yet?".

I'm not sure how to explain this grammatically :( Can someone please help me? Thank you.